# how can I display more data in mongo's web ui?

Tags: mongodb

This is a simple question, but it seems to be hard to know where to ask it. The web ui that one can use for mongodb allows you to select a database and then a collection and then shows you data. But how much data? Only a tiny sliver of the window shows your data and you cannot minimize (AFAIK) any of the other parts of the page. See the screensnap. See the black box I drew on it. That is all of the window that I have for displaying my data. What the heck?

98% of my screen is not my data. And I am here for the data.

[image]

Comment: You can use Compass desktop GUI tool for a better experience. In case you like working with command-line use `mongosh`. Both are free to download and use.

Comment: ... and Compass has an [embedded MongoDB shell](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/compass/current/embedded-shell/).

Comment: Having a not-so-lame web ui would be nice. But, yes, Compass looks pretty good. Running on Ubuntu 20.04.4.

Answer (score 0):

Compass. Even on my desktop Ubuntu 20.04.4.